# webpack same configuration but different outputs

Tags: javascript, webpack

I'm working on a small library that is splitted into several files (for weight purpose). The idea is simply to require a file of a package like:

```
const someStuff = require('lib/somestuff');
const someStuff = require('lib/somestuff');
```

The library should be usable on any platforms like the web or node. This way, I wanted to use the webpack + babel.

Here's the webpack.conf file that I use:

```
module.exports = {
  mode: "production",
  entry: entries,
  output: {
    library: "[name]",
    libraryTarget: "umd",
    globalObject: "typeof self !== 'undefined' ? self : this",
    umdNamedDefine: true,
    path: path.resolve(__dirname, "."),
    filename: "[name].js"
  }
};
```

**Current status**

From that point, running webpack works and well creates the different files.

**The problem**

When I try to require the different files from the module, I sometime have to rely on

```
const someStuff = require('lib/somestuff');
```

And some other time, I have to use:

```
const someStuff = require('lib/somestuff').default;
```

Which is not really consistent for a library.

I don't really understand what's hapenning here since I'm using the same build configuration for all the different submodules.

Do you have any idea?

Comment: Default ES6 exports (`export default ...`) are converted to `exports.default = ....` in CommonJS. https://babeljs.io/repl#?babili=false&browsers=&build=&builtIns=false&spec=false&loose=false&code_lz=KYDwDg9gTgLgBAE2AMwIYFcA28AsAmAbiA&debug=false&forceAllTransforms=false&shippedProposals=false&circleciRepo=&evaluate=false&fileSize=false&timeTravel=false&sourceType=module&lineWrap=true&presets=es2015&prettier=false&targets=&version=6.26.0&envVersion= . So if `lib/somestuff` is an ES6 module, that's why.

Comment: Aw thank you... That was simply that... Thanks for your help :)